# how to add pressure sensors, gyroscopes, and accelerometers to an URDF model?

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please can you tell me how to add pressure sensors, gyroscopes, and accelerometers to an URDF model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48983/how-to-add-pressure-sensors,-gyroscopes,-and-accelerometers-to-an-urdf-model?/) by [DieGo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3660/diego/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The link 1Daniel1 posted has the correct information about how to add a pressure sensor (also known as a bumper) to the URDF of a model. However, whenever you try to listen to the contact sensor topic, you'll most likely get a variation on this message:

```
Error [ContactSensor.cc:237] Contact Sensor[contact_sensor] has no collision[base_link_geom]
```

This is because the contact sensor implementation is broken in the version of Gazebo that comes with Fuerte. The comment thread on Gazebo bitbucket issue 13 has information about how to get a version of Gazebo with working contact sensors. (I'd link to it, but I don't have enough karma.)

---

Originally posted by [Elizabeth C](https://answers.ros.org/users/3009/elizabeth-c/) with karma: 138 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about pressure sensors, but in order to get accelerometers and rotational rates you can use IMU sensor plugin, by adding to your URDF file the following block :

```
<!--IMU : joint , link , sensor  -->
 <joint name="IMU_joint" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>      
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.105"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="IMU_link"/>
  </joint>
<link name="IMU_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="0.001"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="red"/>  
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size=".01 .01 .01"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
<gazebo>
  <controller:gazebo_ros_imu name="dany_car_IMU_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_imu.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>50.0</updateRate> 
    <bodyName>IMU_link</bodyName>
    <topicName>/dany_car_sensors/IMU/data</topicName>
    <gaussianNoise>2.89e-08</gaussianNoise>
    <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
    <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
    <interface:position name="imu_position"/>
  </controller:gazebo_ros_imu>
  <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) with karma: 192 on 2012-11-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suryaprakaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22330/suryaprakaz/) on 2015-09-27**:
That was a great answer. I am a newbie in gazebo and I am trying to learn how to add gazebo elements using plugns. I am unable to find any official documentation that explains how to add an IMU plugin for gazebo.  How do you know which tags to use for which plugins? Is there any conventional method?